# td data-spy is not working in dynamically-created HTML in table

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a product feature comparison chart with product image. I am using a jQuery ajax request to generate comparison html.

[image]

Some time there is a lot of rows for showing comparison features, this time
I need to hold the product image in top of the page. I am using  `data-offset-top="98" data-spy="affix"` attribute.

[image]

This html works perfectly when I am using it as static HTML. But if use the dynamic HTML it's not apply the data-spy attribute when I scroll down the page.

Please see my static HTML design:

```
   <table class="responsive tableContentTable " width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="fixedTableRow" data-offset-top="98" data-spy="affix">
                                                    <ul class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 nav">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <img src="images/product1.jpg" height="" width="" />
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>15 INCH MACBOOK PRO WITH RETINA DISPLAYMGXA2LL/A.</p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="fixedTableRow2" data-offset-top="98" data-spy="affix">
                                                    <ul class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 nav">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <img src="images/product1.jpg" height="" width="" />
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>15 INCH MACBOOK PRO WITH RETINA DISPLAYMGXA2LL/A.</p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr id="feature2" class="featureHeadingRow">
                                                <td colspan="3" class="featureHeading"> Feature Group 2</td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    Price
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="spec_content">$999</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="spec_content">$999</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    Processor Type
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">Intel core i5</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">Intel core i5</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    Hard Drive
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">500GB</label>
                                                    </th>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">500GB</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    MSRP
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">$999</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">$999</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    Release Year
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">2015</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">2015</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    OS Version
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">OS X 10.10 Yosemite</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">OS X 10.10 Yosemite</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    Display Technology
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">LED</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">LED</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="FeatureHeadRow">
                                                <th valign="top" colspan="2">
                                                    Resolution
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">2880*1800</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label class="">2880*1800</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

But when I generate this code from server side (using C#) the data-spy attribute is not working.

Comment: My advice is to post some code that we can look at.

Comment: Sure I will update my question.

Comment: We really need to see the code that's causing the problem, i.e. the dynamic code.